# Minimum Distance Problem with Calculus

Tags: lagrange-multiplier

How do I find the minimum distance from the origin of a point $P$ in the first quadrant on the curve $0 = x^2 + y^2 − 2xy −8xy + 2015$.

This is what I have done so far or attempted. I assumed that the distance from the origin to the curve is given by

$$ d(x,y) = \sqrt{x^2+y^2} $$

and I want to minimize it subject to

$$ g(x)=x^2 + y^2 − 2xy −8xy + 2015 .$$

So I thought I could use the Lagrange multiplier method. But I don't know how to. Can someone please help me?

Comment: You'll make your life easier if you try to minimize $f(x,y) = d(x,y)^2 = x^2 + y^2$. If you're asking about how to use Lagrange multipliers from scratch, I suggest you back to your text or class notes first. Then come back here if you have specific questions when trying to implement the method.

Comment: @simons I am self learning this. I already know what the answer is. I'm looking for how to actually do it

Comment: What have you done so far? (What I'm saying is: we're not going to explain LM from scratch here. But if you're stuck somewhere with them, then show us what you've done so far.) Also, look again at your $g$: is there meant to be two terms in $xy$?

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible to minimize the function $d(x,y)=x^2+y^2$, because if $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ is minimal then $x^2+y^2$ is also minimal. Now it is easy to use the method of Lagrange Multipliers.

Comment: Can you add on please?

Comment: Find the minimum of the function $d(x,y)+ \lambda g(x)$. You can derive this function partially by x and y regarding the Lagrange Multiplier $\lambda$ as an ordinary number. You will have a System of linear equations that you can solve. Finally, Substitute the pair of Solutions $(x,y)$ into $g(x)$ and solve by $\lambda$.

Answer (score 0):

for this case,another way is to use $2xy\le x^2+y^2$

$10xy=x^2+y^2+2015\le 5(x^2+y^2) \iff x^2+y^2 \ge \dfrac{2015}{4}$

if you want max ,$2xy\ge-(x^2+y^2)$